# Drools-Camel 5.6.0.Final library forces camel version 2.9.0

Tags: apache-camel, drools

I am hoping to use Drools-Camel integration on a standalone Java process using Camel route. I am using drools-camel 5.6.0.Final, which seems to be the latest stable version and which brings all the camel 2.9.0 dependencies. Is it possible to use a later version of camel (>2.10)

Comment: Why dont you just give it a try. If you use Maven you can always setup the Camel dependencies you want and then exclude them from drools-camel if needed.

Comment: Yeah I can do that sure. There are not many working examples online so was a bit unsure if it supported by later versions of camel..i wanted to ask online first just in case there is a more recent jar or something I was missing :)

Comment: I have heard Drools/Camel users just use Drools REST API and call it from Camel to integrate them.

Comment: Does this mean I will have to expose the drools-rules decisions via a web service and simply hit that end point via via camel? I was thinking more like having drools rules in the same project as camel route (probably plugging in decision tables)

Comment: Ah okay the REST story is when you run Drools as a separate JVM / node than Camel. Embedding Drools and Camel in the same JVM is also possible but not so often seen, as Drools users often have a Drools cluster that is separated and many different rules it manages.

Comment: Yeah thought so...I have managed to make it work with 5.6.0.Final in a single VM process.  Hmm makes me think if Drools embedded is somewhat heavyweight and overkill for just a single feed. Many thanks.